# Graphic before title - Specific Category

Tags: functions, categories, filters

I am trying to add a "category specific" graphic before the post title of that category. Each category would have a separate graphic. This is what I have so far, any ideas?

```
function new_title( $title ) {
    $new_title = '⚠️ ' . $title;
    return $new_title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'new_title' );
```

- The above adds the graphic to all titles

Comment: you could add a custom image field to the taxonomy, then for each post find the category image

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
function new_title( $title ) {
    if(in_the_loop() && !is_singular('page')) {
        $picArray = array(
            '3' => '&#x26a0;',
            '5' => '&#x26c5;',
        );
        $cats = get_the_category();
        $cat = $cats[0]->term_id;
        $title = $picArray[$cat] . ' ' . $title;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'new_title' );
```

First, we check if we are **in the loop**, and our post **is not a page**. Variable `$picArray` is an associative array of {*category id*} => {*emoji's html identity*} pairs. Of course, you have to build this array to match your values.